# Msdeploy not recognizing site name in query string

Tags: asp.net, command-line, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy an ASP .NET website using web deploy. I can do it from visual studio and it works. But from the command line it fails, specifically around designating the site name. The output window of visual studio shows me its using:

https://server_name:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=MyWebSiteDEV

But from the command line if I use this I get an error. Here's my full command:

> MyWebSite.Deploy.cmd /T /M:"https://server_name:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=MyWebSiteDEV" -allowUntrusted /U:DOMAIN\username /P:password /A:Basic

I get the error:

=MyWebSiteDEV"" was unexpected at this time.

I assume there is some kind of escaping problem around the equals sign, but I cant figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes around the url solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

according to this: http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/12/deploying-web-packages-as-non.html

> Due to an open bug in the current version of Web Deploy (2.1), you
>   can’t specify a query string in the endpoint address if you use the
>   .deploy.cmd file generated by Visual Studio to deploy your web
>   package. In other words, this won’t work:
>
> DemoProject.deploy.cmd /Y
>   /M:https://TESTWEB1/MSDeploy.axd?site=DemoSite /U:FABRIKAM\User
>   /P:Pa$$w0rd A/:Basic -allowUntrusted
>
> I’ve seen some fairly bizarre “workarounds” for this—for example, drop
>   the query string and use an administrator account—this works, but it
>   kind of defeats the object when the whole point of the exercise was to
>   use a non-administrator user to deploy the web package. What you need
>   to do is to use Web Deploy (MSDeploy.exe) directly rather than running
>   the .deploy.cmd file.

single quotes doesn't work for me :(

Comment: sorry for my view, quotes can help, in detail,quotes the whole parameter like this :

"/M:https://server_name:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=MyWebSiteDEV"